# How can I getMediaGalleryImages within a sort order range in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, sorting

I am new to Magento.

How can I getMediaGalleryImages within a sort order range  in Magento? I am new to magento and would like to get all images for a product within a sort oorder range of say 10-20.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())-   >getMediaGalleryImages();?>();?><?php if($_images){?><?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image) if  ($i++ < 8) { $i++;?>
```

Any help is welcome!

Thanks for the answers but, I'm not quite getting it I'm afraid, I want to display thumbs under my products on the product list page. I'm sure the code you have given is correct but I am not implementing it correctly. Here's the full code for that I have at the moment:

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())-   >getMediaGalleryImages();?> 
<?php if($_images){?> 
<?php     $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; if($i>=10 && $i<=20);?>

<a href="#"> 
<img src="<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, $bigImageWidth, $bigImageHeight, 'image',  $_image->getFile()); ?>" class="cloud-zoom-gallery lightbox-group"


title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()); ?>" width="25" height="25" alt="<?    =$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to change code

```
$_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
     $i=1; 
     foreach($_images as $_image){
        if($i > 10 && $i < 20){
        echo $_image['url'];
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by doing following code.

```html
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php if($_images){?>            
    <?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; if($i>=10 && $i<=20): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(108,90); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /><?php  endif; } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Change the range whatever you want.

This is example for product gallery images order from 10 to 20.